# Rails 3. Building an oauth2 provider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth-2.0

I am developing an API in Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to secure it with Oauth2.
In other words, I need to create an Oauth provider. Is there a working gem for Rails 3 out there or perhaps a tutorial on the issue?

**UPDATE**

I know Rails are REST based so I find it very strange that there are no tutorials on how to create a public API and secure it. Does anyone know of any good tutorials. Preferable with oAuth.

Thankful for all help!!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've opensourced an [OAuth2 server implementation](https://github.com/Lelylan/rest-oauth2-server) yesterday.

It's well documented and there is a dashboard to control accesses. Right now I'm searching for somebody who wants to build an engine starting from it, or something cool on top of rack. That's why it is open-source.

Comment: Thank, I hope the community will be part of the project to make it better and better.

Comment: Thank you very much for opening the source. I've learned a lot from it.

Comment: As of now, [Oauth2 server implementation](https://github.com/Lelylan/rest-oauth2-server) is marked as abandoned and suggests to move on to [doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper) or [opro](https://github.com/opro/opro).

Answer (score 31):

Check out this gem https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper

It is for Rails 3, the development it's early stages though.

There's also an example app that you take a look and see how the API is done.

http://doorkeeper-provider.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 24):

https://github.com/intridea/oauth2 is the canonical gem right now for OAuth2 dev. If you are looking for a more complete solution, instead of rolling your own provider code, check out:

- https://github.com/songkick/oauth2-provider
- https://github.com/freerange/oauth2-provider

But I suggest messing around with the oauth2 gem if you aren't very familiar with the flow so that you can learn it better.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any documentation anywhere for this? https://github.com/freerange/oauth2-provider

Comment: That version is based on mongoid btw :) So unless you are using that, I'd suggest the others. I've only messed with building a provider from scratch personally.

Comment: I am using SQL. Do you know of a good guide for building providers in Rails 3?

Comment: I haven't came across any guides for ActiveRecord yet. The OAuth2 spec is still being worked on. Maybe you could use OAuth 1.0? It has been around for much longer and the libraries are a little more mature.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Do you have any links to any libraries or gems for Oauth1?

Comment: Same source, just search github for 'oauth' or 'oauth provider'. The canonical gem is at https://github.com/oauth/oauth-ruby. And the plugin for providers/consumers at https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin

Answer (score 9):

If you are using (or planning to use) devise for authentication, you can use https://github.com/socialcast/devise_oauth2_providable as plugin.

Comment: This is looking very good. I tried it but I cannot figure out how to create a client for example.

Comment: Here is an example client (sinatra) and server (rails) using this devise plugin: https://github.com/aganov/devise-oauth2-provider-client

Comment: From their current [README.md](https://github.com/socialcast/devise_oauth2_providable/blob/master/README.md): "THIS GEM IS NO LONGER MAINTAINED AND IS CONSIDERED DEPRECATED."

Answer (score 5):

I'm developing a rugygem for OAuth2 provider, Rack::OAuth2.
https://github.com/nov/rack-oauth2

It requires to develop models (token, code, client etc) by yourself, but you can get a whole Rails3 sample OAuth2 server here.
https://github.com/nov/rack-oauth2-sample

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking to implement an OAuth2 provider, too! I'm currently experimenting with this https://github.com/assaf/rack-oauth2-server, which seems to be a full-featured OAuth2 server, though it still supports only MongoDB, although implementing support for other DBMS seems simple enough. I am also looking at some of the other options posted here, lots of promising stuff!

Comment: I have used it to implement an oauth2 secured API, it works but it took me a couple of days to wrap my head around it. The author was extremely helpful though

Answer (score 2):

"Doorkeeper is a gem that makes it easy to introduce OAuth 2 provider functionality to your application."

https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper